# Android: Why position rules are different on different API?

Tags: android, position, alignment

I am having problem on Android 2.3.3, the positioning is slightly different:

[image]

On android 4+ is working fine:

[image]

XML file:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_gps" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sGps"
                android:textColor="@color/cWhite"
                android:textSize="35sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:contentDescription="10sp"
                android:text="@string/sInactive"
                android:textColor="@color/cRed" />

</RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_off" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_wifi" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sNetwork"
                android:textColor="@color/cWhite"
                android:textSize="35sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:text="@string/sInactive"
                android:textColor="@color/cRed"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_off" />

    </LinearLayout>
```